# Can I create a form with a form header and footer using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to create forms automatically in MS-Access using VBA.
If it is a simple form, I could create it with the following code.

```
Dim newForm As Form: Set newForm = Application.CreateForm
```

However, a form created in this way does not retain the header and footer.

```
Debug.Print newForm.Section(acHeader).Name

>> Error 2462
```

If you open it in **Design View** and display the form header and footer manually from the menu, the above code will succeed from then on.

```
Debug.Print newForm.Section(acHeader).Name

>> FormHeader
```

Is it possible to add form headers and footers using only VBA?

Comment: Probably yes, but wouldn't it be simpler having a basic "master" form, then copy and modify this when/as needed?

Comment: @Gustav
Thank you.

I was attempting to generate the forms and tables that will be the foundation of the application with the "appinit" command from just one standard module.

It would have been perfect if it was possible, but I will change to the method of preparing the master form in advance.

Comment: OK. You can even save a form named _Normal_, and that form will be used as a master when creating a new form - at least via the GUI; have never tried via code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always try:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFormHdrFtr
```

Comment: Thanks! It was definitely done.
I perused the official Microsoft documentation, but was only looking at "Form.Object" and "Section.Object".
Object". The MS-Access specific "DoCmd" was a blind spot.
Amazing!

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: Could you do me a favour and mark this as the accepted answer please?

Comment: This is my first time, so I don't know much about it.
I can't find a "Like" button for you.
I checked, is that all you need?

Now I want to answer questions and help people in need!

Comment: Nah, you got it, thanks!